# Factoring $3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

I am wondering how to factor 
$$f(n) = 3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$$ the right way. I think the factors are equal to

$$(n - 39.9762)(n - 12.0791)(n + 0.055248)$$

Comment: From [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Roots%5B3n%5E3+-+39n%5E2+%2B+360n+%2B+20%5D) there is exactly one real root, the other two are complex. All roots look quite nasty

Comment: In case this problem comes from some problem book/worksheet, have you dismissed the possibility that there is a typo in the question?

Comment: @Stinking Bishop I haven't thought anything like it

Comment: [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) say that the sum of the roots is $13$, so your factorization can't be correct.

Comment: I took the easy approach on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+3n%5E3+-+39n%5E2+%2B+360n+%2B+20).  I'm sure the other answers are probably more useful in learning about "how".

Answer (score 7):

We want to find a root of
$$
3n^3-39n^2+360n+20=0\tag1
$$
To get rid of the quadratic term, let $n=x+\frac{13}3$; then, we get that
$$
x^3+\frac{191}3x+\frac{9826}{27}=0\tag2
$$
To make the linear coefficient $\frac34$, so that we can apply identity $(4)$, let $x=\frac{2\sqrt{191}}3y$; then, we get that
$$
y^3+\frac34y=-\frac{4913}{764\sqrt{191}}\tag3
$$
Now we can use the identity
$$
\frac14\sinh(3z)=\sinh^3(z)+\frac34\sinh(z)\tag4
$$
by letting $y=\sinh(z)$, and we get that
$$
\sinh(3z)=-\frac{4913}{191\sqrt{191}}\tag5
$$
Since $\sinh(-x)=-\sinh(x)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
n_1
&=\frac{13}3+\frac{2\sqrt{191}}3\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(-\frac{4913}{191\sqrt{191}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{13}3-\frac{2\sqrt{191}}3\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{4913}{191\sqrt{191}}\right)\right)\\
&=-0.055223771734\tag6
\end{align}
$$

---

Once we have a root, we can divide the polynomials
$$
\frac{3n^3-39n^2+360n+20}{3(n-n_1)}=n^2+(n_1-13)n+\left(n_1^2-13n_1+120\right)\tag7
$$
Now we can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to get
$$
\begin{align}
n_2
&=\frac{13-n_1+i\sqrt{3n_1^2-26n_1+311}}2\\[6pt]
&=6.527611885867+i\,8.838056447262\tag8
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
n_3
&=\frac{13-n_1-i\sqrt{3n_1^2-26n_1+311}}2\\[6pt]
&=6.527611885867-i\,8.838056447262\tag9
\end{align}
$$

---

Therefore, the full factorization of $3n^3-39n^2+360n+20$ over $\mathbb{C}$ would be
$$
3(n-n_1)(n-n_2)(n-n_3)\tag{10}
$$
and the factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ would be
$$
3(n-n_1)\left(n^2+(n_1-13)n+\left(n_1^2-13n_1+120\right)\right)\tag{11}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is only one real root which is exactly
$$n_1=\frac{13}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{191} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{4913}{191 \sqrt{191}}\right)\right)\approx -0.055223771734378147887$$
So, numerically
$$f(n) = 3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$$ $$f(n)=3(n-n_1)(n^2-13.055223771734378148 n+120.72095869751148663)$$

Comment: would you be able to provide more explanation? What formulas are you using and how do you come up with 
$$n_1=\frac{13}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{191} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{4913}{191 \sqrt{191}}\right)\right)\approx -0.055223771734378147887$$ and 
how do you get $$f(n) = 3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$$ $$f(n)=3(n-n_1)(n^2-13.055223771734378148 n+120.72095869751148663)$$?

Comment: @randomvalue. Hyperbolic solution of a cubic when only one real root and then division.

Comment: what about the part where you do $3(n- n1)(n^2 - 13.055n + 120.7209) $ why is it n - n1, then n2 - 13.055n (no n1) and then 120.7209 (no n1 or n). Also, what gives 13.055223 and 120.720958?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle (n_1,n_2,n_3)=\\
\Biggl(\dfrac{2}{191} \biggl(-405-2 \sqrt{216010}+\frac{864040 \left(12 \sqrt{216010}+4913\right)}{191 \sqrt[3]{216010 \left(4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120\right)}+4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120}\biggr),\\
\dfrac{2}{191} \biggl(-405-2 \sqrt{216010}+\frac{864040 \left(12 \sqrt{216010}+4913\right)}{-191 \sqrt[3]{-216010 \left(4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120\right)}+4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120}\biggr),\\
\dfrac{2}{191} \biggl(-405-2 \sqrt{216010}+\frac{864040 \left(12 \sqrt{216010}+4913\right)}{191 (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{216010 \left(4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120\right)}+4913 \sqrt{216010}+2592120}\biggr)\Biggr)=\\
( -0.0552238,\,6.52761 + 8.83806\,i,\, 6.52761 - 8.83806\,i)
$

Comment: The roots have already been computed in some of the answers. The main question seems to be **how** to get the roots/factorization.

Comment: what formula are you using to get these expressions?

Comment: @randomvalue [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3342802/602207)

Comment: whoaaao, ok thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP tagged the question *algebra-precalculus*, it is of interest that a serious high school student could show that the OP's function is an injection; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3513622/432081) answer to

$\quad$ [What are the conditions on $a, b, c$ so that $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ is bijective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1984080/432081)

Moreover, if you know the intermediate value theorem and (roughly) graph the function

$\tag 1 p(x) = 3x^3 - 39x^2 + 360x + 20$

as $x \to +\infty$ and $x \to -\infty$, you can argue the surjectivity.

So $p(x)$ is a bijection and has exactly one real root, call it $\alpha$.

Using the intermediate value theorem the student can create an algorithm that converges to $\alpha$ (see next section).

Assuming this has been done we arrive at

$\quad \alpha \approx -0.055223771734378147887$

Therefore, there exists coefficients $b,c \in \Bbb R$ such that

$\tag 2 3x^3 - 39x^2 + 360x + 20 = (x - \alpha)\, q(x)$

where $q(x) = 3x^2 + bx + c$ is an irreducible quadratic.

By multiplying $x - \alpha$ and $3x^2 + bx + c$ together and collecting like terms, we can solve for both $b$ and $c$ by using $\text{(2)}$ and equating coefficients.

Since $-\alpha c = 20$,

$\tag 3 c = -\frac{20}{\alpha} \approx \frac{20}{0.055223771734378147887} = 362.1628760925344692429874874$

There are two ways of getting $b$. We choose the relation $-39x^2 = bx^2 - 3\alpha x^2$ (we don't want to use two approximations), giving

$\tag 4 b = 3 \alpha - 39 \approx 3 \times -0.055223771734378147887 - 39 = -39.16567131520313438386438065208494663238525390625$

---

Following is a crude Python program that gets an estimate for the root $\alpha$.

Once you observe that $p(-1) = -382$ and $p(0) = 20$, the intermediate value theorem guarantees that the root lies between $-1$ and $0$. So the program does a simple binary search.

**Python Program**

```
def y_cubic(x):
    return 3 * x**3 - 39 * x**2 + 360 * x + 20

neg_coord = [-1, y_cubic(-1)]
pos_coord = [0, y_cubic(0)]
it_count = 0


while True:
    P_x = pos_coord[0]
    P_y = pos_coord[1]
    N_x = neg_coord[0]
    N_y = neg_coord[1]
    print(N_x, '< x <', P_x, '        iterations:', it_count)    
    if P_x - N_x < .00000001:
        break
    it_count = it_count + 1
    binSpot = .5 * (N_x + P_x)
    y = y_cubic(binSpot)
    if y == 0:
        print('exact/float answer:', binSpot, it_count)
        break
    if y < 0:
        neg_coord = [binSpot, y]
    else:
        pos_coord = [binSpot, y]
```

***** OUTPUT *****

```
-1 < x < 0         iterations: 0
-0.5 < x < 0         iterations: 1
-0.25 < x < 0         iterations: 2
-0.125 < x < 0         iterations: 3
-0.0625 < x < 0         iterations: 4
-0.0625 < x < -0.03125         iterations: 5
-0.0625 < x < -0.046875         iterations: 6
-0.0625 < x < -0.0546875         iterations: 7
-0.05859375 < x < -0.0546875         iterations: 8
-0.056640625 < x < -0.0546875         iterations: 9
-0.0556640625 < x < -0.0546875         iterations: 10
-0.0556640625 < x < -0.05517578125         iterations: 11
-0.055419921875 < x < -0.05517578125         iterations: 12
-0.0552978515625 < x < -0.05517578125         iterations: 13
-0.05523681640625 < x < -0.05517578125         iterations: 14
-0.05523681640625 < x < -0.055206298828125         iterations: 15
-0.05523681640625 < x < -0.0552215576171875         iterations: 16
-0.05522918701171875 < x < -0.0552215576171875         iterations: 17
-0.055225372314453125 < x < -0.0552215576171875         iterations: 18
-0.055225372314453125 < x < -0.05522346496582031         iterations: 19
-0.05522441864013672 < x < -0.05522346496582031         iterations: 20
-0.055223941802978516 < x < -0.05522346496582031         iterations: 21
-0.055223941802978516 < x < -0.055223703384399414         iterations: 22
-0.055223822593688965 < x < -0.055223703384399414         iterations: 23
-0.055223822593688965 < x < -0.05522376298904419         iterations: 24
-0.05522379279136658 < x < -0.05522376298904419         iterations: 25
-0.05522377789020538 < x < -0.05522376298904419         iterations: 26
-0.05522377789020538 < x < -0.055223770439624786         iterations: 27
```

Comment: If the OP is interested I can (well, I'm pretty sure) add to the answer and show the existence of one and only one real root $\alpha$ by using the intermediate value theorem and the quadratic formula.

Comment: I am interested

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$
P(x)=3x^3-39x^2+360 x+20. 
$$
Then set $x=y+\frac{13}{3}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{3}P(x)=P_1(y):=y^3+\frac{191}{3}y+\frac{9826}{27}
$$
If $\rho_0=\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B}$ is the real root of $P_1(y)=0$, then 
$$
\rho_0^3=A+B+3(AB)^{1/3}(\sqrt[3]{A}+\sqrt[3]{B})=s+3p^{1/3}\rho_0.
$$
Hence $s=A+B=-\frac{9826}{27}$, $p=AB=-\left(\frac{191}{9}\right)^3$ and the equation
$$
X^2+\frac{9826}{27}X-\left(\frac{191}{9}\right)^3=0,
$$
have roots
$$
A=\frac{1}{27}(-4913-12\sqrt{216010})\textrm{ , }B=\frac{1}{27}(-4913+12\sqrt{216010}).
$$
Hence we find 
$$
\rho_0=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{27}(-4913+12\sqrt{216010})}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{27}(4913+12\sqrt{216010})}.
$$
Now $P_1(y)$ have the other two roots such (Vieta)
$$
\rho_1+\rho_2=-\rho_0\textrm{ and }\rho_1\rho_2=\frac{9826}{27}\rho_0^{-1}
$$
Solving
$$
X^2+\rho_0X+\frac{9826}{27}\rho_0^{-1}=0
$$
we get the other two roots of $P_1(y)=0$.

By this way every third degree polynomial equation reduced solving only two degree equations.

NOTE. We have used $\sqrt[3]{-|a|^3}=-|a|$, since the equation $x^3+|a|^3=0$, have solution $x=-|a|$.

Answer (score 1):

**This is just a detailed version of the original answer by @robjohn♦**

\begin{align}
3n^3-&39n^2+360n+20=0 \\
&\implies n^3-13n^2+120n+\frac{20}{3}=0\\
&\!\implies \left( n-\frac{13}{3}\right)^3-\frac{169}{3}n+\frac{2197}{27}+120n+\frac{20}{3}=0\\
&\!\implies \left( n-\frac{13}{3}\right)^3+\frac{191}{3}\left(n-\frac{13}{3}\right)+\frac{9826}{27}=0\\
&\!\implies \frac{27}{8\times191\sqrt{191}}\left( n-\frac{13}{3}\right)^3+\frac{9}{8\sqrt{191}}\left(n-\frac{13}{3}\right)+\frac{4913}{764\sqrt{191}}\!=\!0\\
&\!\implies \left( \frac{3}{2\sqrt{191}}n-\frac{13}{2\sqrt{191}}\right)^3+\frac{3}{4}\left( \frac{3}{2\sqrt{191}}n-\frac{13}{2\sqrt{191}}\right)+\frac{4913}{764\sqrt{191}}\!=0
\end{align}
Now, we can use the identity.
$$
\frac14\sinh(3z)=\sinh^3(z)+\frac34\sinh(z)\implies x^3+\frac{3}{4}x=\frac{1}{4}\sinh(3\sinh^{-1}(x)).
$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{4}\sinh\left(3\sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{3}{2\sqrt{191}}n-\frac{13}{2\sqrt{191}}\right)\right) = -\frac{4913}{764\sqrt{191}}\\
\implies n = n_1\triangleq \frac{13}{3}-\frac{2\sqrt{191}}{3}\sinh\left(\frac{1}{3}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{4913}{191\sqrt{191}}\right)\right)
=-0.055223771734.\tag1
\end{align}

---

Once we have a root, we can divide the polynomial as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{3n^3-39n^2+360n+20}{3(n-n_1)}&=an^2+bn+c\\
&\hspace{-3cm}\implies (an^2+bn+c)(n-n_1)=n^3-13n^2+120n+\frac{20}{3}\\
&\hspace{-3cm}\implies an^3+(b-an_1)n^2+(c-n_1b)-cn_1=n^3-13n^2+120n+\frac{20}{3}
\end{align}
We solve for $a,b,c$ as comparing the coefficients:
\begin{equation}
a=1\hspace{2cm} b=n_1-13 \hspace{2cm} c=120+n_1b=n_1^2-13n_1+120.
\end{equation}
Now we can use the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve $An^2+Bn+C$ to get

\begin{align}
n&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{13-n_1\pm i\sqrt{3n_1^2-26n_1+311}}{2}
\end{align}
Thus, the roots are
\begin{align}
 n_2\triangleq\frac{13-n_1+ i\sqrt{3n_1^2-26n_1+311}}{2}=6.527611885867+ i\,8.838056447262\tag2\\
n_3\triangleq\frac{13-n_1- i\sqrt{3n_1^2-26n_1+311}}{2}=6.527611885867-i\,8.838056447262\tag3
\end{align}

---

Therefore, the full factorization over $\mathbb{C}$ is
$$3n^3-39n^2+360n+20=
3(n-n_1)(n-n_2)(n-n_3),
$$
and the factorization over $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$
3(n-n_1)\left(n^2+(n_1-13)n+\left(n_1^2-13n_1+120\right)\right).
$$