# Confused how to arrive at the factorization of this polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

The polynomial $f(n) = 3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$ I saw has one real root and it's $$n_1=\frac{13}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{191} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{4913}{191 \sqrt{191}}\right)\right)\approx -0.055223771734378147887$$ First, what formula, or how can that be? Second, how is it so, numerically $$f(n) = 3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20$$ $$f(n)=3(n-n_1)(n^2-13.055223771734378148 n+120.72095869751148663)$$?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation ? Concretely here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507142/how-could-i-factor-this-type-of-polynomial)

Comment: @randomvalue Finding the roots of a cubic in the general case is not easy.

Comment: @almagest which is why I asked on a math profession type website?