# algebra trick for dividing polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, algebra-precalculus

I saw that "once have a root, we can divide the polynomials" and somehow

$\frac{3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20}{3(n-n_1)} = n^2 + (n_1 - 13)n + (n_1^2 - 13n_1 + 120)$ I'm noticing a pattern that there's no $n_1$, then have $n_1$, then $n_1^2$ not sure what rule is being used, if any. I'm not sure how to get the expression on the right hand side of the equals sign. This is a question I have for part of the answer given here  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3510325

Comment: First divide through by $3$. Then it’s an exercise of [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

Answer (score 1):

Let us make it using another way.

What you want is basically to find the coefficients $(a,b,c)$ such that
$$3n^3 - 39n^2+360 n + 20 =3(n-n_1)(a n^2+b n+c)$$
Expand and group terms to get
$$(3 c n_1+20)+n (3 b n_1-3 c+360)+n^2 (3 a n_1-3 b-39)+(3-3 a) n^3=0$$ Now, cancel each coefficient. This gives $\color{red}{a=1}$ (that we could have guessed before starting); then remains
$$(3 c n_1+20)+n (3 b n_1-3 c+360)+n^2 (-3 b+3 n_1-39)=0$$ giving $\color{red}{b=n_1-13}$; then remains
$$(3 c n_1+20)+n (-3 c+3 (n_1-13) n_1+360)=0$$ from which $\color{red}{c=n_1^2-13 n_1+120}$; then remains
$$3 n_1^3-39 n_1^2+360 n_1+20=0$$ which is true since $n_1$ is the first compute root of the equation.

Is this clear ?

Comment: yes, this is clear

Answer (score 0):

It's just synthetic division.  If we assume $n_1$ is a root and that $3n_1^3 - 39n_1^2 + 360n_1 + 20 = 0$

Then we can manipulate:

$3n^3 - 39n^2+360 n + 20 = $

$3(n^3 - 13n^2 + 120n + \frac {20}3) = $

$3(n^2*n - 13n^2 + 120n + \frac {20}3) = $

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + n_1*n^2 - 13n^2 + 120n + \frac {20}3) = $

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n_1 -13)n^2 + 120n + \frac {20}3) =$

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n_1 - 13)n*n + 120n + \frac {20}3) =$

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n_1 -13)n(n-n_1) + n_1(n_1-13)n + 120n + \frac {20}3)=$

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n*n_1 - 13n)(n-n_1) + (n_1^2-13n_1 + 120)n + \frac {20}3)=$

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n*n_1 - 13n)(n-n_1) + (n_1^2-13n_1 + 120)(n-n_1) + (n_1^2-13n_1 + 120)n_1 + \frac {20}3) =$

$3(n^2*(n-n_1) + (n*n_1-13n) (n-n_1) + (n_1^2 - 13n_1 + 120)(n-n_1) + \frac {3n_1^3-39n_1^2 + 360n_1 + 20}3)=$

$[3(n-n_1)](n^2 + (n_1-13)n + (n_1^2 -13n_1 + 120)) + [3n_1^3-39n_1^2 + 360n_1 + 20]=$

$[3(n-n_1)](n^2 + (n_1-13)n + (n_1^2 -13n_1 + 120)) + 0 =$

$[3(n-n_1)](n^2 + (n_1-13)n + (n_1^2 -13n_1 + 120))$

==== okay column notation===

$3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n + 20\div 3 = n^3 - 13n^2 + 120n +\frac {20}3$.

And $(n^3 - 13n^2 + 120n +\frac {20}3)\div (n-n_1)=$

$(n-n_1)\begin{cases}n^2&+(n_1-13)n&+(n_1^2-13n_1+120)\\===&===&===&===\\n^3 & -13n^2 & +120n & \frac {20}3 \\n^2*n&-n_1*n^2\\----&----\\&(n_1-13)n^2&+120n\\&(n_1-13)n*n&-(n_1-13)n*n_1\\&----&----\\&&(n_1^2-13n_1+120)n&\frac {20}3\\&&(n_1^2-13n_1+120)n&-(n_1^2-13n_1+120)n_1\\&&----&----\\&&&(n_1^3 -13n_1^2+120n_1 + \frac {20}3)   \end{cases}$

So $ {n^3 - 13n^2 + 120n +\frac {20}3} = ({n-n_1})(n^2+(n_1-13)n+(n_1^2-13n_1+120))+ ({n_1^3 -13n_1^2+120n_1 + \frac {20}3})$ and

$3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n +20 = 3(n-n_1)(n^2+(n_1-13)n+(n_1^2-13n_1+120))+(3n_1^3 -39n_1^2+360n_1 + 20)$

But as $n_1$ is assumed to be a root, $(3n_1^3 -39n_1^2+360n_1 + 20) = 0$ and

$3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n +20 = 3(n-n_1)(n^2+(n_1-13)n+(n_1^2-13n_1+120))$

And $\frac {3n^3 - 39n^2 + 360n +20}{3(n-n_1)} = n^2+(n_1-13)n+(n_1^2-13n_1+120)$

Comment: I'm a little tired right now but not sure I can understand what's going on. Would you be able to comment about synthetic division and how it's used here?

Comment: What's to say other than it exists and works?  If $P(x)$ is a $n$ degree polynomial than $\frac {P(x)}{x-a} = Q(x)  + P(a)$ for some $n-1$ degree polynomial $Q(x)$.  And if $a$ is a root $P(x)$ then $P(a) = 0$ and $\frac {P(x)}{x-a} = Q(x)$.  So if $n_1$ is a root of $3x^3 -39x^2 + 360x + 20$ and you divide it by $(x-n_1)$ you get $3(n^2 + (n_1 -13)n + (n_1^2 -13n_1 + 120))$.  What more needs to be said?

Comment: I'm seeing you add and subtract $n_1$ for whatever reason but don't really see any carry down the coefficient, multiply and subtract, as involved with synthetic division. Idk maybe there was miscommunication and you could try to describe what you're doing successively

Comment: I'm typing it on a single line rather than lying it out in columns.  But I'm doing the exact same thing.  Okay, one thing I did was I factored the $3$ out to begin with.  But as for "carry down the coefficient, multiply and subtract, as involved with synthetic division" I'm doing that a lot.  Example.  The coefficient of $n^3$ is $1$.  So I multiply $n-n_1$ but $1\times n^3$ to get $n^3 - n_1n^2$ and then have to subtract $(-n_1n^2)$ from the next term $-13n^2$ so adding the coefficients is $(-13 + n_1)n^2$.  If you are more comfortable doing it by long column rather than linear line by line..

Comment: ... feel free to go ahead.  You will get the exact same result.  The only differenc is notation.

Comment: ok, I will undo my downvote and change it to upvote. I appreciate the help