# Solving $\beta^3-2\beta^2+(1-\rho)=0$ for $\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

> I need to solve the following equation for $\beta$:
>   $$\beta^3-2\beta^2+(1-\rho)=0$$
>   where $\rho$ is just a constant.

I already tried different kind of methods from the wikipedia page for cubic equations and various other site without luck.

The answer should be: $$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{4}{3}\sin(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin(\frac{27}{16}|\rho|-\frac{11}{16}))$$

I hope someone knows how to handle this equation.

Comment: Just plug into the equation and check if you get the equality.

Comment: I am not supposed to do that. I need to find this solution.

Comment: There are several ways to solve it, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341394/solving-ax3bx2cxd-0-using-a-substitution-different-from-vietas). You can apply a substitution to get rid of $-2\beta^2$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_solution_of_cubic_equations

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908861/using-trig-identity-to-solve-a-cubic-equation